# Pandas cut to categorize non unique scalar list to low medium or high

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that i have a series of scalar list data that i want to categorize to low, medium or high and some of them like `a=[1.0, 1.0, 0.9999999999999999]` and i want to categorize it to low, medium, high in the range of 0 to 1. 
How do i do that? I have tried using pandas cut by defining `labels=['low','medium','high']` and `pandas.cut` but it gives an error that said it needs to be unique.

Comment: `[1.0, 1.0, 0.9999999999999999]` why two `1.0`? That's where the error comes from.

Comment: yes, can it just makes it like [high,high high]?

Comment: so you mean `pd.cut([1.0, 1.0, 0.9999999999999999], bins=[-np.inf, 0,0.5, np.inf], labels=['low', 'medium', 'high'])`?

Comment: yes almost like that, but it seems if i call `pd.cut([0.6, 0.1, 0.9], bins=[-np.inf, 0,0.5, np.inf], labels=['low', 'medium', 'high'])` it would give [high, medium, high] which should be like [medium,low,high]..so what i want is like the range for each category like `0<=low<=0.25, 0.25<medium<0.75, 0.75<=high<=1`

Comment: Please provide the actual code you're using in your question, along with how the output is different from what you want. A [mcve] can help us understand your problem better.

Comment: `bins=[0,0.25, 0.75, 1]`?

Comment: yes thats it, i thought i've tried that before but it doesn't work but its actually working thanks @QuangHoang